# Paypal - Could not access History tab when logged in sandbox account

Tags: paypal, history, sandbox, account

Two months ago, I used the Paypal sandbox site without problem. But recently it took me all day, I don't know what happed with their site.

Yesterday, I tried many times to create new sandbox account after I logged in registerd Business account. Almost times Paypal sandbox site raised some kind undefined errors from sky which I never met. Even I succeeded to create Business sandbox account, that account did not contain any information of API (as I said, it have worked before).

Today, I tried to create other account again, luckily, the API was generated. But in the morning when I logged in sandbox.paypal.com, the site is always broken (layout and CSS were gone and I viewed it on many types of browser)

I was lucky again, until the afternoon, I can access to the sandbox busnisess account after I logged the main Paypal Business account. But I still met other problem: 
I could not access to the History tab, it always redirect me to History tab OF MAIN PAYPAL ACCOUNT, NOT SANDBOX ACCOUNT.
I did research and put the following URL

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_history&nav=0%2e3

but they keep throwing the error: "We'are sorry, the process ...."
Any one experienced it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today it is working again. Maybe Paypal sandbox site has bug and they have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using PayPal's Sandbox for the last 48 hours (24-JUL-14)

"Internal Server Error 500"

"We’re sorry, we can’t complete your payment now. Please try again later."

"This transaction can't be processed..."

"...Timeout.."

Just one big endless barrage of error messages and timeouts.  I did a PayPal integration a few years ago and it was exactly the same nonsense.  In my opinion PayPal are just a scam company with no interest in quality of service.  This will be my last ever PayPal integration.

My advice is avoid them like the plague.  This isn't a personal gripe but a genuine answer to anyone reading this thread.